# How to make transparent div that will catch all clicks

Tags: html

I have web application that design is based on divs.
I need in that application block possibility of clicking on some javascript object.

So I thinking about adding transparent div that will be positioned with z-index on level/layer where I need and will capture all clicks without passing to lower z-index objects?

How this can be done?

Comment: <sarcasm>Have you consulted the world wide web first before posting? There's a new start-up company called the Google that can actually search the interwebs for you and give you an answer to this...it isn't a very big or well known company but, give them a shot?</sarcasm>

Comment: @racecarjonathan <sarcasm>`Such constructive comments`</sarcasm>

Answer (score 0):

Use `absolute` positioning in that covering div. Either don't set any background or set it as `rgba(r,g,b,0)`

Comment: (and don't forget to set the size of that covering div)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is a good design.

I don't know if you know that, but you can add a click listener to the body element itself. Every click will bubble up to body. It's called event delegation. I believe this solves your problem.